# preg_replace - Replacing <br> with nothing in <pre> tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following:

```
$newtext = preg_replace('@<pre>.*<br[/>]*?>?</pre>@si','',$text);
```

and I want it to replace all `<br>, <br />, or <br/>` tags with nothing when between `<pre>` tags, but it isn't working.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: [Regex match HTML wrapped around HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488573/regex-match-html-wrapped-around-html)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to use regular expressions to do a parser's job.  Even if you get it mostly working, you'll be finding edge cases where things break down the road.

See: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)